# Login to website without using a Webview

Tags: android, webview, android-studio

I want to login to a website without using a WebView in one Activity and then, once successfully logged in, start another Activity and display web pages every thing works but when i fill my username and password i click login it works but not loads a page already logged in here is my source code 
this thands fo main_activity i mean login layout

```
private EditText mTextUserName;
private EditText mTextPassword;
private Button mButtonLogin;
public String user_name;
public String pass_word;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
    mTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
    mCheckSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSavePassword);
    mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


    final Button mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            user_name = mTextUserName.getText().toString();
            pass_word = mTextPassword.getText().toString();

            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToNextActivity);


        }
    });
```

and for the webview

```
private WebView webView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://something.com/");
```

hope for your understanding

Comment: clear your question first....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating `mButtonLogin` two times. Delete:

`private Button mButtonLogin;`

and

`mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);`

Also your are assigning these inputs

`user_name = mTextUserName.getText().toString();
 pass_word = mTextPassword.getText().toString();`

but your are not doing anything with them.

If you are trying to send those inputs to the next page, then you have to use `intentName.putExtra("name", value);`

```
 private EditText mTextUserName;
private EditText mTextPassword;
private Button mButtonLogin;
public String user_name;
public String pass_word;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
    mTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
    mCheckSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSavePassword);
    mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


    //final Button mButtonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            user_name = mTextUserName.getText().toString();
            pass_word = mTextPassword.getText().toString();

            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewActivity.class);
    goToNextActivity.putExtra("username", user_name);
    goToNextActivity.putExtra("password", pass_word);

            startActivity(goToNextActivity);


        }
    });
```

in the other activity (where your Webview is created) you have to use `intentName.getExtras()` for getting usernmane and password

Comment: oh can you plese be more specific ?

Comment: I Edited my answer, but remember that here we dont write code for each other, we HELP each others to figure out the problem in our own written code

Comment: @Andrew Remember also that you can also upvote or downvote answers when they satissfy or unsatisfy your question

Comment: i am trying but it says requires 15 reputation i am new there and thats why maybe